# How to compile C++ using MinGW on Windows?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw

I'm getting the following error

`cannot find -lstdc++`

`collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

it's a simple Hello World program.

`g++ version` returns

```
g++ (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) 9.2.0
```

`g++ -v <filename.cpp>` returns

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-9.2.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --target=mingw32 --disable-win32-registry --with-arch=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-build-format-warnings --prefix=/mingw --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --enable-nls --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC Build-2'
Thread model: win32
gcc version 9.2.0 (MinGW.org GCC Build-2)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/ hw.cpp -quiet -dumpbase hw.cpp -mtune=generic -march=i586 -auxbase hw -version -o C:\Users\move78~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQus9Kp.s
GNU C++14 (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) version 9.2.0 (mingw32)
compiled by GNU C version 9.2.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.21-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/mingw32"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/mingw32
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/backward
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../include
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include-fixed
End of search list.
GNU C++14 (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) version 9.2.0 (mingw32)
compiled by GNU C version 9.2.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.21-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: cb31672760a9c1b42d1ddb86616116cd
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o C:\Users\move78~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cctjBjko.o C:\Users\move78~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQus9Kp.s
GNU assembler version 2.32 (mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.32
COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/collect2.exe -plugin c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/liblto_plugin-0.dll -plugin-opt=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\move78~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxROszG.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -Bdynamic -u ___register_frame_info -u ___deregister_frame_info c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../crt2.o c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/crtbegin.o -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0 -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/lib -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../.. C:\Users\move78~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cctjBjko.o -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lmingwex -lmingw32 -lmingwex -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lmingwex -lmingw32 -lmingwex -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmsvcrt c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/crtend.o
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What command do you use to compile?

Comment: thank you for replying

I'm using the following command
g++ <filename.cpp>

Comment: Something is not right here. What's the output of `g++ --version` and `g++ -v filename.cpp`? Where did you get your MinGW?

Comment: g++ --version returns 
g++ (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) 9.2.0

g++ -v <filename.cpp> returns
https://ibb.co/b222zfB

I got MinGW from mingw.org

Comment: Can you add both to the question as text? The second one got cut off, and pictures are harder to read.

Comment: I didn't use plain MinGW for some time, but last time I checked it was way inferior to MinGW-w64. (No multithreading support, older GCC version, etc.) Instead of figuring out what's wrong here, you can install a shiny new GCC 10.2 from MSYS2 (they ship a MinGW-w64-based GCC).

Comment: As text please, not as a picture. See [this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: I've tried to edit the question.
and can you please share the link for the the compiler that you've mentioned

thank you

Comment: sorry for the image. here's the text file

https://file.io/qYGzfk1l3IgW

Comment: https://www.msys2.org/ It's harder to install though. I suggest removing the MinGW you currently have, just to be safe. Then follow all steps on that page, and then install the compiler by running `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`. Then, restart the MSYS2 shell by running `mingw64.exe` (if done correctly, it should say `MINGW64` in pink text, instead of `MSYS` or `MINGW32`), otherwise it won't be able to find the GCC it just installed.

Comment: Your link gives me error 404. Can you add the text to the question itself, as text rather than a link?

Comment: this should work, hopefully

https://jpst.it/2f0HM

Comment: do you think MinGW-w64 will work better than MinGW ?

Comment: It looks like you're missing libstdc++ in your setup. But as mentioned MinGW is old, you should really use MinGW-w64. You can install it from MSYS2 or get a standalone build from http://winlibs.com/ .

Comment: I was able to make it work. 
From winlibs.com I downloaded the mingw-w64 zip archive and placed the extracted folder in my C drive. After that I updated the PATH. 
Now, cpp source files compiles and runs perfectly. 
However, please let me know if I did anything incorrectly or inefficiently. 

thank you for your help and guidance - @HolyBlackCat & BrechtSanders

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 things to build:

1. Your tools (like `g++.exe`) need to be in your `PATH` (or specified via their full path when calling them, e.g. `C:\mingw\mingw32\bin\g++.exe`).
2. The compiler needs to be able to find the include files. If needed you can add include paths (pointing to the folder, not the actual file) using `-I` flags (or you can use `C_INCLUDE_PATH` (for C) and `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` (for C++) environment variables).
3. The linker needs be able to find your libraries (like `libstdc++.a`). If needed you can add library paths (pointing to the folder, not the actual file) using `-L` flags (or you can use `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable).

If you use MSYS2 shell these things should already have been set up.

The standalone build from http://winlibs.com/ looks for relative locations and should just work wherever you extract it on your disk.

You didn't mention which shell you were running your commands from (Command Prompt, PowerShell, MSYS), but it's important the above is respected correctly in whatever shell you are using.

As far as I know http://winlibs.com/ works in MSYS shell, Command Prompt and PowerShell (though parameters starting with `-` need to be put in quotes when using PowerShell).